# Cannot find header file in subfolder

Tags: xcode, file, header, imagemagick, magick++

I am trying to compile my file witch is using Magick++ in Xcode. But it connote find the header files that are in subfolders. for example :

```
#include <magick++/include.h>
```

if in search header file I put the recursive then there is no error for  `#include <include.h>` but there is still error for `#include <magick++/include.h>`.

So Somehow it has problem with the header file in subdirectories. 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I just realize there is error in my sentence above, it should be like this:

Comment: f in search header file I put the recursive then there is no error for #include<include.h> but there is still error for #include<magick++/include.h>